# Alternatives to Sword of the Divine

Tags: league-of-legends

Since the latest patch, Sword of the Divine was removed from the Summoner's Rift. To sum up again in short:

> [image: SotD thumbnails]
>   **Stats:**
>   +45% attack speed
>
> **Passive:**   This item does not grant any attack speed while on cooldown. Champion kills reduce the current cooldown by 50%.
>
> **Active  Unique:**   You gain 100% attack speed and 100% critical strike chance for 3 seconds or 3 critical strikes. 60 second cooldown.

<sub>information taken [from LeagueOfLegends wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_the_Divine)</sub>

I valued sword of the divine as an extremely powerful steroid for MissFortune, up to the point of chosing it over Phantom Dancer and Statikk Shiv, since it provided me much utility and "burst potential", especially in combination with w and q to instantly nuke squishier enemies.

I am now struggling to find a similarly fight-breaking item / build choice.

What are my alternatives (especially as situative steroids) for Ad-Carries in general?

Comment: RIP SotD rengo :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best choice with similar stats would be **Yomuus Ghostblade**. It provides Attack damage, Critical strike chance and Armor Penetration passively while it also has an active that gives you Attack speed and Movement speed. While it doesn't have the same amount of burst potential as an SotD, it certainly does provide more utility.

Armor Pen and Attack damage are great since your abilities scale with it and the bonus movementspeed is pretty sweet too.

If you're looking for some extra burst while not loosing too much sustained damage I'd suggest running a Statikk Shiv.

If you just want sustained damage the best choice would be a Phantom Dancer.

Comment: Very true. Youmuu's Ghostblade + Statikk Shiv is an excellent combo for AD carries, especially for the ones who use their skills alot, like Lucian.